# Interpretation of results for a simple Gatling scenario with 1 user and reachRps 20000

Tags: scala, spray, gatling

---

### Premises

1. Rest API in scala / spray
2. Simple method that always returns OK
3. I try to achieve an average of 20k requests per second
4. Both machines (tester & tested) well configured (EC2 dedicated servers, each one with only its API & Gatling, configuration files
   sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1025 65535"
   echo 300000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/nr_open
   echo 300000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max, /etc/security/limits.conf, ulimit -a --> 65535)

---

This is my simple test file scenario, just 1 user:

```
    setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1) during(60 seconds)))
    .throttle(
              //reachRps(20000) in (60 seconds),
              //holdFor(1 minute)
              //,
              jumpToRps(20000),
              holdFor(1 minutes)
             )
    .protocols(httpConf)
```

I try to achieve 20k rqs (maximum) in 60sec or jump directly to 20k and maintain there along 1 minute.

This is always my results after executing Gatling script:

```
Simulation finished
Parsing log file(s)...
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...

================================================================================
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                         60 (OK=60     KO=0     )
> min response time                                      0 (OK=0      KO=-     )
> max response time                                      2 (OK=2      KO=-     )
> mean response time                                     1 (OK=1      KO=-     )
> std deviation                                          0 (OK=0      KO=-     )
> response time 50th percentile                          1 (OK=1      KO=-     )
> response time 75th percentile                          2 (OK=2      KO=-     )
> mean requests/sec                                  1.017 (OK=1.017  KO=-     )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t  800 ms  t > 1200 ms                                            0 (  0%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
```

I don't understand what means exactly these results... or, perhaps, I'm not configuring the right scenario for my goal.

I tried with several scenaries:

```
    //setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(20000)).protocols(httpConf))         
    //setUp(scn.inject(Users(200000).ramp(10)).protocols(httpConf))
    //setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(20000) during(1 seconds)).protocols(httpConf))           
    //setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(20000) during(1 seconds))).protocols(httpConf)
   //setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1500) over (60 seconds)))
   //setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(50000)))
   //      .throttle(jumpToRps(50000),
   //                holdFor(1 minutes))
   //      .protocols(httpConf)

   setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1000) during(30 seconds)))
    .throttle(
              reachRps(20000) in (30 seconds),
              holdFor(1 minute)
              //,
              //jumpToRps(20000),
              //holdFor(1 minutes)  
             )
    .protocols(httpConf)
```

So, I don't know how to configure my scala test file for, simply, getting a value like that:

```
> mean requests/sec                                  20000 (OK=20000  KO=-     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get throttle right. From the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/general/simulation_setup.html#simulation-setup-throttling):

> You still have to inject users at the scenario level. Throttling tries
>   to ensure a targeted throughput with the given scenarios and their
>   injection profiles (number of users and duration). It’s a bottleneck,
>   ie an upper limit. If you don’t provide enough users, you won’t reach
>   the throttle. If your injection lasts less than the throttle, your
>   simulation will simply stop when all the users are done. If your
>   injection lasts longer than the throttle, the simulation will stop at
>   the end of the throttle.

How can you expect reaching 20000 rps whith only injection 1 user per second?

Comment: Dear Stephane, thanks a lot for your explanation. Simply, I didn't understand the concept of "Throttle". However, I'm still looking for a right configuration for, simply, getting "> mean requests/sec 20000 (OK=20000 KO=- )". So, I tried differents examples, as my re-edited question shows. And I continue trying without success...